# how to get columns and rows for React '@material-ui/data-grid' from object data

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

I'm trying to get data from a mockapi, and have it on my data grid.

data grid needs to define rows and columns.

i defined those manually for a practice, but i want to get object data from axios and map those into rows and columns

```
async function getBoards() {
    const response = await axios.get(
        'https://60aba7e...
    );
    return response.data;
 ...
const {loading, data, error } = state;

<DataGrid rows={props.rows} columns={props.columns} pageSize={10} onRowSelected={(e) => {showPopUp(e.data);}}/>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this to map the data out

```
const detailsRows = rows.map((row) => {
return {
  id: row.item_id,
  model: row.model_no,
  title: row.title,
};
```

and then pass it in to DataGrid like this

```
<DataGrid rows={detailsRows} columns={props.columns} pageSize={10} onRowSelected={(e) => {showPopUp(e.data);}}/>
```